# AngularJS DataBinding is not working

Tags: html, angularjs

Here i have some code that is not working and i do not know why. Could anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>        
    <head data-ng-app="">
        <title>Directives and Data Binding angular_js</title>
    </head>        
    <body data-ng-init="names=['John Smith','John Doe','Jane Doe']">Name:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />{{ name }}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="person in names"></li>
        </ul>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

http://postimg.org/image/pi38k566f/

I am using Opera and i've also tried on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcNa0B5T3SQd3i1cKitH?p=preview)

`data-ng-app=""` should be in the body tag:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <title>Directives and Data Binding angular_js</title>
    </head>
    <body  data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="names=['John Smith','John Doe','Jane Doe']">
    Name:<br/><input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>{{ name }}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="person in names">{{person}}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added `{{person}}` in the repeat to display the array data.

Comment: oh thank you. I am a beginner so i hope you'll forgive for mistakes like this :D thank u once again.